# Duplicate tag keys found in IAM Role while deploying aws cdk package

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I created a simple cdk package which defines a single resource (aws Lambda).

During `cdk deploy` step, the associated IAM role failed creation with error:

```
10:55:30 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role                         | AenvaiyeRoleD5AD7F7D


Duplicate tag keys found. Please note that Tag keys are case insensitive. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInput; Request ID: f2148918-9281-44ae-8c8d-f45b108fcb22; Proxy: null)   new Role (/workplace/vasuaror/XYZ/src/XYZCDK/node_modules/monocdk/lib/aws
```

This is the CFN template generated for the related IAM role (extracted relevant portion):

```yaml
AenvaiyeRoleD5AD7F7D:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: "2012-10-17"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/AWSXRayDaemonWriteAccess
      RoleName: Aenvaiye-Role
      Tags:
        - Key: application
          Value: proSPERAPP
        - Key: HighCastleBlueprintID-3c5b7308-d575-48bd-bd28-bce1ff16a0d9
          Value: "8.0"
        - Key: HighCastleDeploymentType
          Value: Pipelines
        - Key: lambdaFunction
          Value: Aenvaiye
        - Key: production
          Value: "false"
        - Key: stagePurposes
          Value: Personal
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: PromotionSellerPayablesEventResponder-Infira-personal/Aenvaiye/Role/Resource
```

There is no tag key being duplicated in the CFN template. Even going by the code of the library used to generate CFN (library defines an L3 construct of aws-cdk), there seems to be no duplication of tag keys.

I am unsure why I'm getting this error!

Comment: Please check the CloudFormation events for the error messages, I deployed a stack with the resource you've shown us and it worked just fine in eu-central-1. Can't reproduce.

Comment: Could you show your CDK code for the role?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of CFN, the tags defined on CFN get inherited into the resources defined in template. Check the following:

- Make sure tags are not inherited
- If inherited, be sure to remove tags (with the same key)that are defined on CFN stack

Hope this helps.

Comment: 0

Similarly, in my case on a terraform deploy, a tag `environment` globally set at provider-create time conflicted with a downstream imported module that was looking to set `Environment` as a tag on a resource (IAM Role).